# Analiytic Continuation of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, analytic-continuation

For the given curve $γ$ fix the regular in domain C\ $γ$ branch of $f(z) = ln z$ by $f(1) = 0$. For
that branch find the value of its analytic continuation f(−3) =?

[image]

I just know that we have to work on the argument. I already have : $ln(z) = ln|z| + iarg(z)$. Since f(1) = 0, arg(0) = 0. But as with this curve we never touch (-3)

Answer (score 1):

Within the region we can travel counterclockwise from $1$ to $-1$ to $2.$ Thus $\log 2=\ln 2 +i(2\pi).$ We do the same kind of thing from $2$ to $3,$ obtaining $\log 3 = \ln 3 +i(4\pi).$   Now finish by making a counterclockwise half-loop from $3$ to $-3$ to arrive at $\log (-3) = \ln 3 +i(5\pi).$

Comment: So I'm wondering how you find it, I mean I don't understand we know that f(1) = 0, that doesn't mean that the curve must begin at 1 and follow the same drawing? and so in this way, I don't understand why log(2) = ln 2 + i(2$\pi$)

Comment: After some reflection, I think I understand, it's because we are in the domain C \ $\gamma$ , and so we create another way to go to -3 passing by 1 and after -1 and then 2....  ?